# Is it possible to Enable SP SessionStateService for "a specific" SP Web application?

Tags: 2010, powershell, session

I have a SP2010 Server (enterprise edition) that hosts many web applications. Only one application requires a SQL Session State service.

The Powershell command Enable-SPSessionStateService does not specific a web application as target.

Can I Enable Session state service on a specific Web application in my SP2010 Server without affecting the other web applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This PowerShell command *enables* session state for the entire farm, but does not turn it on for any web applications.

To make a web application use session state, you'll need to change this in the web.config:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true"
```